# Extract matching strings ids in JSON dataset from input file using Unix

Tags: json, linux, shell, unix, jq

I have JSON data from which I extract ids for the various customers using .jq. With the help of UNIX commands, I have fetched this JSON data through API calls. Now, I am trying to get all the IDs for that customer.

With the help of the below script if the customer has more than one id my data looks something like this

**Script**

```sh
appKey=12345678999999999988999
tokenInXml=$(curl -X POST \
      "APIURL/authentication" \
      -H 'Accept: application/xml' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
      -H "Finicity-App-Key: $appKey" \
      -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
      -d "<credentials>
            <partnerId>11111111111111111</partnerId>
            <partnerSecret>asdfdsfggfgfgfdss</partnerSecret>
        </credentials>")

SUBSTRING=$(echo $tokenInXml| cut -d'>' -f 4)
token=$(echo $SUBSTRING| cut -d'<' -f 1)

COUNTER=0

while IFS= read -r line
do
    customerId=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
        
    (( COUNTER++ ))

    response=$(curl --fail --silent \
     -H "App-Key:$appKey" -H "App-Token:$token" \
     -H "Content-Length:0" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" \
     -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Exclude-Metrics:true" \
     -X GET "APIURL/${customerId}/reports" -d '' )
    
    rep=$(echo "${response}" |
       jq -r '.reports[] | select(.id | contains("-")|not)| .id')
        
done < "inputfile.txt"
```

Example JSON file for customer id 123456788 will look like this

```json
{ "data": [
  { "id": "dkfjgh48sdfg", "abc": "sdfdsf", "pqr": "sdkfj" },
  { "id": "sdfg742sdfg2", "abc": "aksjdfj", "pqr": "alkejf" },
  { "id": "sdfjk7df3dfg", "abc": "smdfb", "pqr": "sdjkfhakj" },
  { "id": "pltrsg2rt4tl", "abc": "artgrre", "pqr": "sfeewrwg" } ] }
```

Output:

```
123456789 hksdf21sdfi
aflire65sfdh
sdfghklj256v
sdkfjh2dr7gd

123456788 dkfjgh48sdfg
sdfg742sdfg2
sdfjk7df3dfg
pltrsg2rt4tl
```

Here the 123456789 123456788 are the customer ids and the alphanumeric string is id. I want to filter only those id's whose last four-digit matches with the input list which looks like this

```
Input List

123456789 256v
123456788 dfg2
123456788 t4tl
```

Expected output:

```
123456789 sdfghklj256v
123456788 sdfg742sdfg2
123456788 pltrsg2rt4tl
```

Comment: Your sample JSON doesn't have the string `123456789` (or `123456788`) in it at all. How could that possibly be part of the actual output?

Comment: The JSON file belongs to the customer id 123456788 and it is the response when we hit API call for the customer id 123456788. API call picks up the customer ids present in the input file through for loop.

Comment: If it's part of the response it should be in your sample response.

Comment: I have updated my command line with the script I am using for extracting data, I hope now it gives more clarity to the entire scenario

Comment: Yep, that helps a lot. If you have a bash variable you want to pass into jq, `jq --arg varname "$varname"` is your friend; then you can use `$varname` in your jq code to refer to the value.

Comment: BTW, trying to extract values from XML that way is not necessarily going to be all that reliable. If you get a token including a literal ampersand, f/e, it'll be represented as `&amp;` but the real value is `&` -- a legit XML parser will know to do that translation, but code using `cut` won't. Lots of other similar cases; so it's preferable to use xmllint, xmlstarlet, or similar tools to extract data from XML in bash.

Comment: (btw, your jq uses `reports` but your sample data has `data`; do try to make them match up enough that someone can get your current output from the [mre] you provided).

Comment: Also, your sample input isn't actually valid JSON right now; trying to run it through jq results in `parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 7, column 9`. Again, be sure that your sample data and your sample code can be used to create your stated current output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step solution.

1. transform the input into an easy-to-use "dictionary"
2. look up user ids in the new object using the last 4 chars of .id in .data

Transform the user list input.

```
$ jq -Rs -f users.jq < users.txt | tee  users.json 
{
  "eeee": "5",
  "sdfg": "44",
  "dfg2": "66",
  "3dfg": "12",
  "t4tl": "69",
  "aaaa": "1",
  "bbbb": "2",
  "cccc": "3",
  "dddd": "4"
}
```

database.json (input)

```
{ "data": [
        { "id": "dkfjgh48sdfg", "abc": "sdfdsf", "pqr": "sdkfj" },
        { "id": "sdfg742sdfg2", "abc": "aksjdfj", "pqr": "alkejf" },
        { "id": "sdfjk7df3dfg", "abc": "smdfb", "pqr": "sdjkfhakj" },
        { "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "abc": "smdfb", "pqr": "sdjkfhakj" },
        { "id": "nope........", "abc": "smdfb", "pqr": "sdjkfhakj" },
        { "id": "____________", "abc": "smdfb", "pqr": "sdjkfhakj" },
        { "id": "pltrsg2rt4tl", "abc": "artgrre", "pqr": "sfeewrwg" } ] }
```

Select objects from data that match the input

```
$ jq -r --argjson users  "$(< users.json )" -f match.jq < database.json 
44 dkfjgh48sdfg
66 sdfg742sdfg2
12 sdfjk7df3dfg
69 pltrsg2rt4tl
```

##### Scripts

**users.jq**

```
  [
    split("\n")[]|
    split(" ")|
    select((.[]|length > 0))
  ]
  | map({  (.[1]|tostring)  :  (.[0]|tostring)  })
  | add
```

**match.jq**

```
.data[]
| (.id|split("")|reverse|.[0:4]|reverse|join("")) as $l4
| { orig: ., uid: $users[$l4] }
| select(.uid != null)
| "\( .uid ) \( .orig.id )"
```

##### Input

users.txt

```
  5 eeee
  44 sdfg
  66 dfg2
  12 3dfg
  69 t4tl
  1 aaaa
  2 bbbb
  3 cccc
  4 dddd
```

Comment: I'm deliberately ignoring the way you obtain the data because that seems irrelevant.